# how to print horizontally,vertically and diagonally in assembly language

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

my code is this

```
debug
a
mov cx,000a
mov ah,02
mov dl,30
int 21
inc dl
loop 0107
mov dl,0a
int 21
mov dl,0d
int 21
mov cx,0009
mov dl,20
int 21
mov dl,31
int 21
push dx
mov dl,0a
int 21
pop dx
inc dl
loop 011e
push dx
mov dl,0a
int 21
mov dl,0d
int 21
pop dx
mov cx,0009
mov dl,31
int 21
push dx
mov dl,0a
int 21
mov dl,0d
int 21
pop dx
inc dl
loop 0139
int 20
```

Actual output [image: output]

desired output:

[image: output should be like this]

Comment: Notice that after the first line, each line has 2 characters on it, separated by 0 or more spaces.  Unless you use cursor-movement system calls, you should print both characters as part of the same loop.  (Your code is an unreadable uncommented mess.  DOS `debug.exe` doesn't even support labels, so it's horrible.  Use a better assembler so you can give meaningful names to your branch targets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be the knack of your program:

```
...
165B:011E CD21          INT 21
165B:0120 52            PUSH    DX
165B:0121 B20A          MOV DL,0A
165B:0123 CD21          INT 21
165B:0125 5A            POP DX
165B:0126 FEC2          INC DL
165B:0128 E2F4          LOOP    011E
...
```

After that the cursor is on the last row and you have to move it upwards. You can achieve this with functions 02 and 03 of BIOS interrupt 10

Change

```
165B:012A 52            PUSH DX
165B:012B B20A          MOV DL,0A
165B:012D CD21          INT 21
165B:012F B20D          MOV DL,0D
165B:0131 CD21          INT 21
165B:0133 5A            POP DX
```

to

```
mov ah, 03
mov bh, 00
int 10
mov ah, 02
mov dl, 00
sub dh, 9
int 10
```

You have to adjust the jumps behind it. Change

```
loop 0139
```

to

```
loop 013E
```